# HOw to get category ID in zencart for PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to zencart but also totally not familiar with php. What I want to ask is: how can I   get all products in the  one specific category  for my php code? My store is here:
http://www.polish-your-art.com/boutique/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=29
The category in this case is "pay what you want" id 29.  I use very nice code from zencart forum but is it applicable only for one specific products. Here is the code:

```
     ***  /* Alternate code to change text for donation.
          as per https://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=115475
         */
// the alternate text - products_id would be the id of your donation product:
 if ($_GET['products_id'] == 103){
     $add_text = 'How much you want to donate: ';
     $button_image = 'donate.png';
     $button_alt   = 'Donate';
 } else {
     $add_text = PRODUCTS_ORDER_QTY_TEXT;
     $button_image =  BUTTON_IMAGE_IN_CART;
     $button_alt   =  BUTTON_IN_CART_ALT;
 }   
 // show the quantity box -
 // Everything is the same here, except at very beginning and at end:
 $the_button = $add_text . '<input type="text" name="cart_quantity" value="' . (zen_get_buy_now_qty($_GET['products_id'])) . '" maxlength="6" size="4" /><br />' . zen_get_products_quantity_min_units_display((int)$_GET['products_id']) . '<br />' . zen_draw_hidden_field('products_id', (int)$_GET['products_id']) . zen_image_submit($button_image, $button_alt);
            }
    $display_button = zen_get_buy_now_button($_GET['products_id'], $the_button);
  ?>
  <?php if ($display_qty != '' or $display_button != '') { ?>
    <div id="cartAdd">
    <?php
      echo $display_qty;
      echo $display_button;
            ?>
          </div>
  <?php } // display qty and button ?>
<?php } // CUSTOMERS_APPROVAL == 3 ?>
***
```

I am sure this line with productID can be change to get the category. I just do not know how to change it.

```
if ($_GET['products_id'] == 103){
```

Can you please advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_GET['cPath'] == 29){
```

this should retrieve your category id number.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it right now. Much appreciate.

Comment: update:just tried this and this did not help it. It is still working on one product only ...even if I change it for cPath 29... I just find this on other forum:"..., cPath is never a hybrid of category and product ... it is only the nesting of categories."

Comment: please post your new code.  when i go here:

http://www.polish-your-art.com/boutique/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=29&products_id=103

i see the donate.

when i got here:

http://www.polish-your-art.com/boutique/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=29&products_id=109

i do not see the donate.

and yet, $_GET['cPath'] defintely equals 29 in both cases.

i do not really understand your comment from the zen-cart boards.  a get variable from the URL will have nothing to do with nested categories (at least in this situation).

Comment: OK. I change it now to this: // the alternate text - products_id would be the id of your donation product:
 if ($_GET['cPath'] = 29){
     $add_text = 'Amount: $';
     $button_image = 'donate.png';
     $button_alt   = 'Donate';
 } else {   ... but it is till not working.

Comment: marta, if the change in code does not work and things remain the same, i would suggest that you have this code elsewhere and you have not properly used the template overriding in zen-cart.  are you sure this code is not elsewhere in a template directory?

Comment: I just look fot the phase : Add to Cart Box--> and it is only in one file: tpl_product_info_display.php.

Comment: The change work but is changing only the one product...although I change it to apply for the entire category.

Comment: above your if statement, add the following 2 lines of code: print_r($_GET);
die(__FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__); then got to the product page that is NOT working and send a screenshot.  you can then remove those 2 lines of code.

Comment: Hallo,where sould I add those lines? To the same file?  tpl_product_info_display.php?

Comment: just above the if statement.  then grab a screenshot of the page, and then remove the lines.

Comment: It is working. I made a mistake with quantity box. If this should work the quantity box have to set to  Yes, Show Quantity Box. So it is working now. Thank you for your help.